# How to return values in a textbox on different pages

Tags: ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have a data-set called Customers where I am running a simple sql query (select * from Customer). Instead of displaying the information from the data-set using a table or matrix , I want to use a textbox instead i.e. the `textbox` will return the `CustomerID` of each `Customer` on separate pages.

I am using the expression below in the texbox:

```
=First(Fields!CustomerId.Value, "Customers")
```

where `"Customers"` is the data-set containing the `sql` query.

Not sure if this can be done?

Comment: quick question any particular need you want Customer Id on Text Box. I understand you need each customer Id on separate Page but this can be done using Matrix or table as well.

Comment: Instead of displaying the information in a table or matrix, i am trying to display the information in the following format: Customer Name and Customer Location on one line, Customer ID and Customer Phone just below it. So basically having each customer's info displayed on each page in different tecboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I got you requierement and here is how I solved it.

I used Table but added some logic to it.

1. I grouped row by CustomerID.
   [image]
2. Then I added Pagre break on Group as below
   [image]
3. Then I deleted Header row as we do not need in our case
4. Now I added extra column before Customer ID as you need to show like Label and then it's Text
5. I named it Customer ID:
6. same goes for Customer Name:
7. I added Row Inside group below
   [image]
8. Now I added Country as Text and in next column Country as value from Table

This is how my Table looks right now

[image]

Note I just made Border colour of each cell as white, because I assume you need to show like free text or something
Below is how output look like.

[image]

[image]
[image]

and so on.

You can use your imagination to make changes as you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Definitely looks like what i am trying to achieve. Will play around with this.